# Checking the value of an optional boolean

Tags: javascript, typescript

In TypeScript, how can I check if an optional boolean value is present (either true or false) vs undefined?

Basically, I want to say:

- If boolean is true, use boolean value
- if boolean is false, use boolean value
- If boolean is undefined, use true

```
class MyTest {

    private myBool: boolean;

    constructor(
        config: {
            myBool?: boolean,
        }
    ) {

        // If boolean value is true or false, use boolean value
        if (config.myBool) {
            this.myBool = config.myBool;
        }
        // If boolean value is undefined, use true
        else {
            this.myBool = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `typeof config.myBool !== "undefined"`...? Alternatively, you could use nullish coalescing: `this.myBool = config.myBool ?? true`.

Comment: Both of these work, thanks! If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.myBool = config.myBool === undefined || config.myBool;
```

Comment: If they wanted the default value to be false, then they'd have to change this entire line of code, though. Compared to using `config.myBool ?? true` and `config.myBool ?? false`.

Comment: @caTS I was considering the case when only undefined should be handled, not null. It's a simple change anyway: `config.myBool !== undefined && config.myBool`.

Comment: Oh well, that seems a little complicated, logic-wise, whereas I could just change true to false and be on my way :p